# Formula for "adjusted mean" - Is this correct?

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, adjustment

I am working on a software project involving statistical analysis of myoelectrical signals (EMG).

One client requested the calculation of "adjusted average" for a given signal interval. His description is the following:

$$\text {AdjustedMean} = \text{Mean} + \frac{\text{StandardDeviation}^2}{\text{Mean}}$$

He sent me this explanation about it:

> "The adjusted mean is used to correct for situations with high standard deviation, such as those found with Electromyography."

I googled a lot, but couldn't find any reference to such formula. Most references to "adjusted mean" are related do ANCOVA, and then the mean is adjusted to some other variable, not relative to the standard deviation of the same variable.

(EDIT, as per WHuber request) My client has these other considerations about what he intends to do with the adjusted average:

> "The adjusted mean presents a better linear correlation with the exerted muscular force (measured by a dynamometer) than the unadjusted average. This is more evident for stronger contractions / forces, because then more motor units are recruited and thus the electrical values oscillate more widely".

Some other paper I've read DEFINES the EMG amplitude envelope as the (moving?) Standard Deviation itself, a somewhat different definition of the more common rectification + smoothing.

Comment: That formula is reminiscent of the formula for the arithmetic mean of a lognormal distribution, which might be appropriate for strictly positive values with standard deviation large compared to the mean. I don't know how to format a formula either, but you can see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lognormal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments

Comment: It would be interesting to know what your client intends to *do* with these statistics.  Will they be used for formal testing?  Visualization?  Interpretation or description of the signals?  (A [recent review of EMG signal processing](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3821366/) has an entire page (see Table 4) of statistical summaries in use, some of them very specialized, but this one is not among them.)

Comment: @whuber I added more context, with the same words my client used. Thanks for the link, gonna take a look.